# Why does referring to a class in (python) pyglet.image cause heavy cpu load on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, debugging, cpu, pyglet

I'm using python's pyglet module (python 3 on Windows). When I refer to any classes within pyglet.image, python's CPU usage jumps up and doesn't drop until I exit python. For example:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
C:\Anaconda3>python.exe
Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:06:10) [MSC v.1
600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyglet #No problem!
>>> pyglet.image.ImageData #Heavy CPU load until I exit python
<class 'pyglet.image.ImageData'>
```

Is this expected behavior? **Why does mentioning this class** (not even instantiating it) **lead to such high CPU load?**

Systems I've tested:

- Windows 7 desktop with Anaconda python 3.4.3 and pyglet installed
  through 'pip install pyglet': High CPU usage (my problem)
- The same Win7 desktop with Anaconda python 3.4.3, but pyglet
  installed through 'pip install
  hg+https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet': High CPU usage.
- The same Win7 desktop with python 3.5 from python.org and pyglet
  installed through 'pip install pyglet': High CPU usage.
- Fedora 22 Lenovo laptop with python 3.4.2 and pyglet 1.2.1 installed
  through dnf: no problem.
- Windows 10 HP laptop with Anaconda python 3.4 and pyglet installed
  through 'pip install pyglet': no problem.

Is it possible this is hardware-dependent?

Comment: You could try profiling it: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/profile.html

Comment: Do you get a traceback if pressing ctrl-C?

Comment: The input which leads to high CPU usage returns immediately. If I Ctrl-C, I don't get a traceback.

Comment: No issues found on python 2.7 win 7 64 bit

Comment: I think it not Python. It is Anaconda's framework which create the problem

Comment: Mayukh Sarkar, check my recent edits; I've done the same test with "vanilla" python on the same machine, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably related to the following lines on the [module](http://pyglet.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.1.2.dfsg-2/pyglet_2image_2____init_____8py-source.html):

```
# Initialise default codecs
from pyglet.image import codecs as _codecs
_codecs.add_default_image_codecs()
```

The order for loading the default [codecs](http://pyglet.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.1.2.dfsg-2/pyglet_2image_2codecs_2____init_____8py-source.html) is:

```
# Add the codecs we know about.  These should be listed in order of
# preference.  This is called automatically by pyglet.image.

# Compressed texture in DDS format
try:
    from pyglet.image.codecs import dds
    add_encoders(dds)
    add_decoders(dds)
except ImportError:
    pass

# Mac OS X default: QuickTime
(...)

# Windows XP default: GDI+
(...)

# Linux default: GdkPixbuf 2.0
(...)

# Fallback: PIL
(...)

# Fallback: PNG loader (slow)
(...)

# Fallback: BMP loader (slow)
(...)
```

Because of lazy loading `pyglet.image` is only loaded when you refer to something, and you are probably using one of the slow fallbacks. If that is the case maybe you can try installing/uninstalling the codecs so that you use one at a time and find out if the problem is indeed with the codecs. Posting your versions of these codecs may help reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I won't be able to check this until tomorrow, but this is productive, so you get the bounty.